# waf check_python_headers fails with python installed with pyenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv, waf

I'm trying to build a project using the [waf build tool](https://waf.io/).
The build fails in the configure step when checking the python headers.

I narrowed the problem down to this minimal example of my wscript:

```
def options(ctx):
        ctx.load('compiler_c')

def configure(ctx):
    ctx.load('compiler_c python')
    ctx.check_python_version((2,7,0))
    if int(ctx.env.PYTHON_VERSION[0]) == 2:
        print ('→ Configuring for python2')
    else:
        print ('→ Configuring for python3')
    ctx.check_python_headers(features='pyext')
```

I use python versions (3.6.12 & 3.7.9) that I installed with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) on Ubuntu 20.04.

I run that like this and it fails with an error that I cannot make sense of:

```
$ python waf configure
Setting top to                           : /home/myuser/waf-test
Setting out to                           : /home/myuser/waf-test/build
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc
Checking for program 'python'            : /home/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/bin/python
Checking for python version >= 2.7.0     : 3.7.9
→ Configuring for python3
python-config                            : /home/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/bin/python-config
Asking python-config for pyext '--cflags --libs --ldflags' flags : yes
Testing pyext configuration                                      : Could not build python extensions
The configuration failed
(complete log in /home/myuser/waf-test/build/config.log)
```

```sh
$ tail -n 20 build/config.log
[1/2] Compiling build/.conf_check_d3b505aa7ab58576b6d76a2fc3091b1f/test.c
['/usr/bin/gcc', '-fPIC', '-g', '-fwrapv', '-O3', '-I../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/include/python3.7m', '-DPYTHONDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages"', '-DNDEBUG', '../test.c', '-c', '-o/home/myuser/waf-test/build/.conf_check_d3b505aa7ab58576b6d76a2fc3091b1f/testbuild/test.c.1.o']
[2/2] Linking build/.conf_check_d3b505aa7ab58576b6d76a2fc3091b1f/testbuild/testprog.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
['/usr/bin/gcc', '-shared', 'test.c.1.o', '-o/home/myuser/waf-test/build/.conf_check_d3b505aa7ab58576b6d76a2fc3091b1f/testbuild/testprog.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-L/home/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu', '-L/home/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib', '-lpython3.7m', '-lcrypt', '-lpthread', '-ldl', '-lutil', '-lm', '-lpython3.7m', '-lcrypt', '-lpthread', '-ldl', '-lutil', '-lm']
err: /usr/bin/ld: /home/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.7m.a(pylifecycle.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `Py_VerboseFlag' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
from /home/myuser/waf-test: Test does not build: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/waf-test/.waf3-2.0.20-36f5354d605298f6a89c09e0c7ef6c1d/waflib/Configure.py", line 335, in run_build
    bld.compile()
  File "/home/myuser/waf-test/.waf3-2.0.20-36f5354d605298f6a89c09e0c7ef6c1d/waflib/Build.py", line 176, in compile
    raise Errors.BuildError(self.producer.error)
waflib.Errors.BuildError: Build failed
 -> task in 'testprog' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)
Could not build python extensions
from /home/myuser/waf-test: The configuration failed
```

Note that this problem does not appear with python 3.8.6 that was also installed with pyenv. I can configure without errors.

**My questions:** How can it be that the python versions in pyenv differ in a way that waf checks fail in one version and not in another?
Since I simply install the versions with `pyenv install 3.6.12`, what do I need to change in the install so my build succeeds?

Comment: I am not sure, that this is a problem coming from waf - the error message come from the library ``can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC``. Have you tried compiling in command line based on waf -v with an actived pyenv?

Comment: @user69453 thanks for your comment. I'm not completely sure if I understand what you mean. I can see that the problem is in the linking step, but I don't understand what makes it fail.
The problem I describe in my question is completely reproducable in an activated pyenv with the code that I show. `waf -v` does not give any more information than I already provide.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is that, when creating the test program to check if `pyext` is correctly set, the compiler complains about the fact that `pylifecycle.o` included in `libpython3.7m.a` is non relocatable ie non compiled with the `-fPIC` flag.

As the code fragment generated by waf is compiled with -fPIC, it seems that the problem is that `pylifecycle.o` in `libpython3.7m.a` is not compiled with `-fPIC`, which makes sense as it is in a static library. Maybe the problem is that it uses the `.a` archive lib instead of the shared object one ie the `.so`.

Check if you have the shared object version of libpython ie `libpython3.7m.so`.